# The type javax.persistence.EntityManager is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa, dependencies

My maven project on eclipse generates the above error all of a sudden even though the project have been running successfully before the error pop up. All the required dependencies have been added in the pom.xml file and the project runs properly but develops this error and I can't tell what caused it. I have tried to remove and add the dependencies yet the error persist. This same type of error made me installed a new eclipse IDE (Eclipse IDE for java developers 2021-06) and carefully transfer the files to the new IDE. The project was working fine in the new IDE for some days and then all of a sudden generate the same error again. Please what is happening and how can I fix this? Your guide will be greatly appreciated. Below is a screenshot of my maven dependencies:

[Screenshot of my maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9I8i.jpg)

The dependencies in my pom.xml file are as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Your Maven errors are at the lines 85 and 115.

Comment: Thank you, @Zorglube. 
Are you referring to the pom.xml file? It doesn't indicate any error and has no line 115. Lines 85 and 115 on the Service.java file (the file that has the error) are just creating JPQL query objects.

Comment: I'm referring to your maven console out.

Answer (score 1):

After several trials, I have been able to solve the problem. I removed the javax.persistence-api-2.2 jar from the Maven Dependencies by removing the dependency entry in the pom.xml file. I decided to do this because I discovered that the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar also has the javax.persistence package which has all the required classes for persistence operation. Immediately I refresh my project, the javax.persistence-api-2.2 jar was removed and the error disappeared. I think there could have been a conflict on which javax.persistence to use for my declaration: javax.persistence-api-2.2 jar or the one in the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar. Perhaps it was referencing the former which is not applicable -However, I'm not too sure of this reason but it worked when I removed javax.persistence-api-2.2 jar.